# Convert byte[] to JSONObject java

Tags: java, json, kafka-consumer-api

I've seen many links here on SO and other places with similar issues but none was of help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;


public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {

    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream;

    public static Queue<JSONObject> message = (Queue<JSONObject>) new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

    public ConsumerThread(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream){
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            byte[] msg = it.next().message();
            System.out.println(new String(msg));
            message.add(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(msg));
        }
    }

}
```

This is giving error on the last line:

```
message.add
```

I just want to convert this `byte[]` to `JSONObject` that can be pushed to Queue and I'm not sure what is the issue.

Comment: `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(msg)` returns a Base64 string. A `String` is *not* a `JSONObject`. You'll have to build a `JSONObject` which *contains* the string; this can be added to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;


public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {

    public static final String JSON_MESSAGE_FIELD_NAME = "message_b64";

    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream;

    public static Queue<JSONObject> message = (Queue<JSONObject>) new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

    public ConsumerThread(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream){
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            byte[] msg = it.next().message();
            System.out.println(new String(msg));

            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put(JSON_MESSAGE_FIELD_NAME, DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(msg)); 

            message.add(json);
        }
    }

}
```

?